# How can i checkout particular commit from the git scm from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have following code to checkout master branch, if i want to checkout particluar commit from master branch, how can i achieve it.

```
parameters {
        stringParam("COMMIT_SHA", "", "[Required] Short SHA of the commit used to build the image")
    }
definition {
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git {
                    remote {
                        url("https://github.mywork")
                        credentials("mytoken")
                    }
                    branches("master")
                }
            }
            scriptPath("azure/pipelines/build_service.jenkins")
        }
    }
```

I have tried

```
branches(master: ${COMMIT_SHA})
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the available options that can be used in the branch specifier when checking out a pipeline with Git:

[image]

So in your case you can just use: **`branches(COMMIT_SHA)`**